# Writing from android program to localhost phpmyadmin

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been solving this problem for 2 days now, but still nothing.

This is my code I use in my main activity:

```
   public void InsertData(final String name, final String email){

        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                String postReceiverUrl = "http://192.168.1.71/insert_data.php";
                Log.d("Hello", "postURL: " + postReceiverUrl);


                String NameHolder = name ;
                String EmailHolder = email ;

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", NameHolder));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", EmailHolder));

                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                    Log.d("come on man", "it works");

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                return "Data Inserted Successfully";
            }
```

When I run this code in my Emulator it works, but when I upload it to my Samsung S3 phone, it doesnt work. The data doesn't get pushed.

This is my `insert_data.php`

```
<?php

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "-";
$password = "-";
$dbname = "test";

 $con = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$dbname);

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];                             
 $Sql_Query = "insert into GetDataTable (name,email) values ('$name','$email')";

 if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){

 echo 'Data Submit Successfully';

 }
 else{

 echo 'Try Again';

 }
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I am wondering why this code doesn't work on my phone. I also tried using my localhost IP address instead of `localhost` in my PHP file, but still it wasn't working.

Comment: What error(s) does PHP return? My first guess is your db doesn't allow external connections by default or that you are breaking your query by not escaping the values in the `INSERT` statement.

Once your issue is more clear I can provide a solution.

Comment: I don't get any errors. it just says, "Data Submit Succesfully", but I dont see any data in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem.

I had to go to my config file of Apache `httpd.conf`. 
You have to search for the lines that look like this:
[image]

I have added line 192 and 193 myself, they weren't there in the beginning, thats what  solved the problem.

Special thanks to @SISYN for hinting me about the "My first guess is your db doesn't allow external connections by default".